# Best way to deter pests (gophers, squirrels, rabbits) from my fruit and vegetable area

Tags: fruit-trees, pests, raised-beds, rodents, leaf-vegetables

I have planted fruits trees and vegetables (raised beds) in my side yard.  Every summer i have visitors (not sure which ones) in the form of gophers, squirrels, rabbits (maybe), mice (maybe) that eat my fruits and vegetables.  I would be happy to share some of my production with my visitors but sometimes I feel it is unfair (they ate my entire Kale plant and did not leave me anything).  Any ideas on how to deter these visitors from eating my share of the loot.  I cover my vegetable raised beds with a net but somehow these guys get in from under the net (not the raised bed).  Any recommendations on what i can do without hurting them and doing it organically?

Comment: I already have a backyard fence but these visitors (gophers, squirrels) get in by climbing over the fence or digging from under.  So a fence wont' help.  Another fence around the raised bed may help but then I also have fruit trees to protect.  I looked at the post and got a few ideas.

Comment: Since you got some ideas from that other post, would you consider it a duplicate?

Comment: I make a spray using crushed garlic and ginger and water, I spray the ground lightly and the containers and for me this has worked, most animals don't like the smell or taste of garlic and ginger also helps with bugs.

Comment: @DebraBrooks can you send me the recipe in terms of the proportions you used?  I hope it did not deter bugs that help with pollination

Comment: I love you that you don't want to hurt your neighbors!  I have mass bunnies, especially since I started feeding them when my stupid neighbor shot my beloved feral cat that took care of baby bunnies and rodents.  I have a green house and simply using bunny fencing keeps them out perfectly.  Gophers and squirrels are a bit different and I have both but no problems.  I also put out hay for deer and peanuts for squirrels and gophers are into the grubs in the soil.  Harmony.  I am not into companion planting and spraying with smelly stuff.  What do you know are your neighbors?

Comment: @stormy All I know is they are nocturnal so I don't see them during the day but when I go out in the morning my produce is bitten into or gone.  Particularly, I had some nice Kale growing last year and one fine day it was gone.  Unfortunately that was my only kale and I lost it.  They got an unfair share :-)

Comment: Sounds like rabbits.  Have you put up bunny fencing?  Pretty cheap and fairly simple.  Make sure the bottom is buried at least 4 " into the soil.  Bunnies can dig under but they usually prefer to use existing tunnels or gaps.  They don't jump over a little fence 2-3' high.  Amazingly enough.  They could but they don't.  I usually FEED animals that need training to get into harmony with my environment.  Easy and cheap fix.  Go out at night with a flash light.  You'll be able to see 'eyes' shining quite brightly.  The bunny fence works well and cats for all else!  Feral cats.  Keep yours indoors

Comment: In addition to rabbits, there must be something else since they climb my fruit trees and eat the fruits.  I also have a net on the raised beds to protect my vegetables but they get inside somehow